# Is Cassandra use two phase commit when config write multi replicas ?

Tags: cassandra, distributed-system

From [How is the consistency level configured?](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html) , the write must to written to multi nodes when configed ; So will cassandra rollback the successful node when the successful nodes don't meet the config .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consistency level defines how many replicas need to answer to consider result (write or read) as successful. In case of write, if not enough replicas answered, the rollback won't happen - data could be written to some nodes, and then writes could be propagated via repairs, hints, etc.

I recommend to read corresponding part of the [DSE Architecture Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntDataConsistencyTOC.html) - it has very good explanation how it works.